# Android Templates something like ASP.net Masterpages?

Tags: android, templates

I am trying to work out if android has something like what masterpages is in ASP.Net, or perhaps the {{> yield }} template in meteor's IronRouter.

Essentially what I want is the ability to define a template and specify the content within the construction of the xml.

Think of a simple card like control, where the content is specified at design time in the xml.

Maybe define the control something like this:

```
<myCardControl>
  <layout>
    <text />
    <content />
    <button />
  </layout>
</myCardControl>
```

and then use it in other layout like a component:

```
<layout>
   <myCardControl>
      <image />
   </myCardControl>
   <myCardControl>
      <image />
   </myCardControl>
   <myCardControl>
      <layout>
         <text>...or other controls etc.
      </layout>
   </myCardControl>
</layout>
```

If anyone can understand what I am on about, can you point me in the right direction. I am new to Android dev and working out the best way to do things. I have looked around but cant find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is no concept like ASP.net Masterpages in Android. But you can create something like this.

You can create an `Activity` which is the template. All the content (the part which is changing) goes inside a `Fragment`. Load this fragment inside the `Activity`.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
    <common views />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        .... />
</LinearLayout>
```

To do `Fragment` operation (add, replace, remove) inside the `container` `FrameLayout` use the following code.

```
// get fragment manager
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

// add
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment());
// alternatively add it with a tag
// trx.add(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment(), "detail");
ft.commit();

// replace
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment());
ft.commit();

// remove
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_placehodler);
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.remove(fragment);
ft.commit();
```

To repeat elements among these `Fragment`, you can create an `xml` file anduse the `include` tag to include this layout.

For example,

Create a common xml.

common.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
    <common views>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can include this layout in your code as follows,

fragment1.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
    <include
        ..
        layout="@layout/common"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment2.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
    <include
        ..
        layout="@layout/common"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Fragment Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)
[Include tag example](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-include-tag-layout-example)

Hope you get the idea. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the considered response, I was pretty much aware of these in-code methods, I was really looking for an in XML answer. You say there isn't any way yet, so I guess that is the answer.